# Polynomial matrix equality and controllability

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, control-theory, matrix-rank

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $I$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Show that for any polynomial $n$-vector $X_0(s)$ with elements of degree $n-1$ or less, we can always find polynomial vectors $X(s)$ and $U(s)$ such that $(sI-A)X(s)-BU(s)=X_0(s)$, if and only if $$\text{rank}[sI-A\quad B]=n\quad\forall s\in\mathbb{C}$$
i.e., $\{A,B\}$ is controllable.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry I don't get it. So?

Comment: Sorry about the distraction!

Comment: @copper.hat You actually proved one direction that I didn't know. For the other direction, it seems we just need to prove the case $X_0(s)=e_i$, the $i$th standard vector, $\forall i=1,...,n$, and that makes me think of the Bezout's identity though I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that $X_0(s)$, $X(s)$ and $U(s)$ are polynomials, by collecting terms containing the same power of $s$ one can write the initial equation also as

\begin{align}
- \begin{bmatrix}
A & B
\end{bmatrix} y_0 &= v_0, \tag{1a} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0
\end{bmatrix} y_{i-1} - 
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B
\end{bmatrix} y_{i} &= v_i,\ \forall\,i=1,\dots,k, \tag{1b} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0
\end{bmatrix} y_k &= 0, \tag{1c}
\end{align}

with $k \leq n-1$, $v_i \in\mathbb{R}^n$, $y_i \in\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ and

\begin{align}
X_0(s) &= \sum_{i=0}^k v_i\,s^i, \tag{2a} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
X(s) \\ U(s)
\end{bmatrix} &= \sum_{i=0}^k y_i\,s^i. \tag{2b}
\end{align}

From now on I will use $y^x_i$ and $y^u_i$ to denote the components of $y_i$ associated with $X(s)$ and $U(s)$ respectively. Solving $(1c)$ yields $y^x_k = 0$, substituting this in $(1b)$ and solving it yields the following expression for each $y^x_{i-1}$

$$
y^x_{i-1} = v_i + A\,y^x_i + B\,y^u_i,\ \forall\,i=1,\dots,k, \tag{3}
$$

where initially each $y^u_i$ can be chosen to be anything. However, these choices get constrained when one also wants to satisfy $(1a)$. Namely, when substituting each expression for $y^x_i$ in $(1a)$ yields

$$
\sum_{i=0}^k A^i B\,y^u_i = \underbrace{-\sum_{i=0}^k A^i v_i}_{r}, \tag{4}
$$

which is equivalent to driving the discrete time system associated with $(A,B)$ from the origin to $r$ in $k+1$ time steps. It can be noted that if the polynomial order of $X_0(s)$ has $k < n-1$ (i.e. $v_k \neq 0$ and $v_i = 0,\ \forall\,i > k$) it might not be possible to drive such system to $r$ in $k+1$ steps. However, iff $(A,B)$ is controllable it should always be possible to drive the system to $r$ in $n$ steps, thus $k = n-1$.

Comment: A fundamental and beautiful answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the forward implication, we prove the contrapositive. Suppose for some $\lambda$ (necessarily an eigenvalue of $A$) there is some $y \neq 0$ such that
$y^T \begin{bmatrix} \lambda I -A & B \end{bmatrix} = 0$.

Now choose $X_0(s) = y$. Note that
$y^T ((\lambda I-A) X(\lambda) -B U(\lambda)) = 0$ but $y^T X_o(\lambda) = \|y\|^2$.

The  following was motivated by Kwin van der Veen's answer (and George C's comments) but expressed in a manner that I can more easily understand:

For the reverse implication, first note that if we can show that for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists polynomials $U, X$ such that
$y = (sI-A) X(s) - B U(s)$, then clearly $s^ky = (sI-A) s^kX(s) - B s^kU(s)$ and hence for any polynomial $X_0$, we can find some polynomials $U,X$ such that $X_0 = (sI-A) X(s) - B U(s)$. In particular, we need only consider $X_0$ of the form $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

If the rank condition holds, then $A,B$ is cc. and so there is some sequence
$\upsilon_k \in \mathbb{R}^m$ that steers the system
$\xi_{k+1}= A \xi_k + B \upsilon_k$ from $\xi_0 = 0$ to $\xi_n = -y$.

If we take $\upsilon_k = 0$ for $k\ge n$ and $|z| > \sigma(A)$ the $z$ transform gives
$z\hat{\xi} = A \hat{\xi}+B \hat{\upsilon}$, with $\hat{\xi}(z) = {\xi_1 \over z} + \cdots + {\xi_{n-1} \over z^{n-1}} + {-y \over z^n} + \cdots$ (recall that $\xi_0 = 0$), and similarly for $\hat{\upsilon}$.

Multiplying by $z^{n-1}$ gives $z^n\hat{\xi} = z^{n-1}A \hat{\xi}+z^{n-1}B \hat{\upsilon}$, and equating the terms with non negative powers of $z$ gives the
equality
$\xi_1 z^{n-1}+ \cdots + \xi_{n-1} z -y = A(\xi_1 z^{n-2}+ \cdots + \xi_{n-1} ) + B (\upsilon_0z^{n-1} + {\upsilon}_1 z^{n-2}+ \cdots + \upsilon_{n-1} )$.

Finally, letting $X(s)= \xi_1 s^{n-2}+ \cdots + \xi_{n-1} $,
$U(s) = \upsilon_0s^{n-1} + {\upsilon}_1 s^{n-2}+ \cdots + \upsilon_{n-1} $ gives
$(sI-A) X(s)-B U(s) = y$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can understand what you are saying. However, it appears to me that the rank condition can be relaxed. We don't need $[sI-A\quad B]$ to be full rank $\forall s$. Instead, we just need it be full rank for $s=1,...,n$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @GeorgeC: My answer may be a little too glib, but I do not have time at the moment to expand. The statement is an **iff**, so the other direction needs to hold too.

Comment: What confused me is that it seems that, if $\text{rank}[sI-A\quad B]=n$ for $s=1,...,n$, then for all $X_0(s)$ there always exists $X(s)$ and $U(s)$ such that....  However, $[sI-A\quad B]$ always has full rank unless $s$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Thus, we can always find $n$ distinct points that are not the eigenvalues of $A$ to construct the isomorphism. This then means that in fact we don't need the condition that $\{A,B\}$ is controllable. What's going wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much. But I still have a question about your proof. Suppose $\{A,B\}$ is not controllable, but $\{1,...,n\}$ are not the eigenvalues of $A$. So given an arbitrary $X_0(s)$, we can find $X_k$ and $U_k$ satisfying $(kI-A)X_k-BU_k=X_0(k)$ for $k=1,...,n$ because $[kI-A\quad B]$ is full rank. Then the isomorphism will give us an $X(s)$ and $U(s)$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @GeorgeC: No, the above shows that if $(A,B)$ is not cc. then there is some $X_0$ for which there is no $(X,U)$ satisfying the equation.

Comment: Yes I know that. I agree $\{A,B\}$ need to be controllable. It's just that I don't know what's wrong in the argument of my previous comment. It seems that we can always find $X_1,...,X_k$ and $U_1,...,U_k$ as long as $1,...,n$ are not eigenvalues of $A$. Then by isomorphism we get $X(s)$ and $U(s)$, isn't it?

Comment: That works for one direction.

Comment: But doesn't that mean we can get $X(s)$ and $U(s)$ for whatever $X_0(s)$ even if $\{A,B\}$ not controllable? (we just need $1,...,n$ not be the eigenvalues of $A$)

Comment: No. If the rank condition holds then you can solve. If it doesn't then there is an $X_0$  that is not in the range.

Comment: But any $X_0$ is in the range of $[kI-A\quad B]$ because $k$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ and thus $[kI-A\quad B]$ is full rank, isn't it?

Comment: I replaced the **iff** by then in my hint.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your effort. Now I have another question regarding the "only if" part of your proof (i.e., given rank condition, show the existence of solution). Because of full-rankness of $[kI-A\quad B]$, we can find solutions $X_k$ and $U_k$ for $k=1,...,n$, and reconstruct $X(s)$ and $U(s)$ based on the isomorphism. However, how do we know these $X(s)$ and $U(s)$ will also satisfy $(sI-A)X(s)-BU(s)=X_0(s)$ for points other than $s=1,...,n$?

Comment: Yes, because we choose $X,U$ to be the unique degree $\le n-1$ polynomials that interpolate the $X_k,U_k$. If they match at $n$ points then they are the same.

Comment: Elements of $X, U$ are of degree $\leq n-1$. So elements of $(sI-A)X(s)-BU(s)$ may have degree $n$. Then don't we need $n+1$ points of match to ensure $(sI-A)X(s)-BU(s)=X_0(s)$? Thank you.

Comment: If $X_0$ is of degree $n-1$ then the left hand side must be too.

Comment: But by the construction, the LHS may have degree $n$. We first choose $X_k, U_k$ (not unique) that satisfy the wanted equation at $k=1,...,n$. Next, based on $X_k, U_k$ we construct the unique $X(s), U(s)$ whose elements are of degree $\leq n-1$ that satisfy $X(k)=X_k, U(k)=U_k$. Now going back to the original equation, we see that $(sI-A)X(s)-BU(s)$ will (very likely) have degree $n$. What the above process guaranteed is that it will match $X_0(s)$ at $s=1,...,n$. An $n$th degree polynomial can match a degree $n-1$ poly at $n$ points with no problem, but that does not mean they are the same.

Comment: @GeorgeC: I think you have found a flaw in my reasoning, however I don't have time to fix it now so will delete my answer momentarily. Perhaps interpolating at one more point will suffice, but I need to think it through.

Comment: @GeorgeC I updated my answer to something I am more comfortable with. I wanted to find a direct connection of the fact that $A,B$ is cc. to the polynomials $X,U$.

Comment: Sorry, did you use $u_k$ or $v_k$ to denote the input? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: @GeorgeC: Thanks for catching that, I meant $\upsilon$ (Greek upsilon).